# Which model is the most appriopriate in this case for QTreeView?

Tags: c++, qt, data-modeling, qtreeview, qlistwidget

I want to display the following data in a QTreeView:

> 1. Men:
>
>    Mark
>
>    Steve
>
>    James
> 2. Women:
>
>    Ann
>
>    Joyce
>
>    Emily
> 3. Female teenagers:
>
>    Rebeca
>
>    Alex
> 4. Male teenagers:
>
>    Sam
>
>    Ian

I use the Qt library version 4.8.

I'm wondering, which QAbstractItemModel would is suitabe for it?

It looks to me like I should use the QDirModel - this is how I want my QTreeView to look like. But it's dumb: I won't display strings like directories.

It's quite surprising, but although QTreeView provide the features I need, there is no model that seems suitable for my data.

To make it clear: I need something like a QListWidget with these for items. They should be expandable, so that the user could see the names of people of certain *type*.

Sorry for the stupid example. How can I do it in Qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple tasks the QTreeWidget (without any external model) is good enough.

```
QTreeWidget* tree = new QTreeWidget(this);

QTreeWidgetItem* itemMen = new QTreeWidgetItem({"Men"});
QTreeWidgetItem* itemMark = new QTreeWidgetItem({"Mark"});
QTreeWidgetItem* itemSteve = new QTreeWidgetItem({"Steve"});

tree->addTopLevelItem(itemMen);
itemMen->addChild(itemMark);
itemMen->addChild(itemSteve);
```

If you need more control, use the combination of `QStandardItemModel` + `QTreeView`.

```
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
model->setRowCount(1); // Top level item count.
model->setColumnCount(1);

QTreeView* tree = new QTreeView(this);
tree->setModel(model);

QStandardItem* itemMen = new QStandardItem("Men");
QStandardItem* itemMark = new QStandardItem("Mark");
QStandardItem* itemSteve = new QStandardItem("Steve");

model->setItem(0, 0, itemMen);
itemMen->setRowCount(2);
itemMen->setColumnCount(0);
itemMen->setChild(0, 0, itemMark);
itemMen->setChild(1, 0, itemSteve);
```

**Edit**

With the `QTreeView::setRootIsDecorated()` you can show or hide the controls for expanding and collapsing top-level items.

Comment: Will the user be able to show and hide the items which represent the names? At the beginning I want the user to be able to see only the types of people and I want to display to him the names when he clickes on a type of people.

Comment: Yes of course: `QTreeWidget::collapseItem(item)`/`QTreeWidget::expandItem(item)` or `QTreeView::collapse(index)`/`QTreeView::expand(index)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I need:)

Comment: So, I implemented the solution you suggested. But I have a "title" of my QTreeView which is *1*. I mean a line (a bar) above my list. Could you please tell me what it is so I could get rid of it? QTreeView doesn't have a title or a bar.

Comment: Could you please upload a screenshot?

Comment: @user2738748 I think it's the header. You can hide it with [`setHeaderHidden(true)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#headerHidden-prop).

Comment: @thuga, yes, it was a header. Thank you.

Comment: @Tomas, could you please tell me how I can access the name that the user clicked on my list? I use the doubleClicked(const QModelIndex & index) signal, but I am only able to get the type of people, not the name. I use the index.row() method for that.

Comment: Try the index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString()